# For a Cordova project, what is the difference between the "Distribution" and "Release" configurations?

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

The MSDN topic for [Packaging an app built with Visual Studio Tools for Cordova](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757048.aspx) mentions the "Distribution" configuration, but doesn't elaborate on how it differs from the "Release" configuration.  What is the difference between the "Distribution" and "Release" confgurations for a Cordova project?

Comment: The term "Release configuration" makes little sense for a project that uses a scripting language.  There is just no difference at all between a Debug and a Release build like there is in a C++ or C# project, it is the exact same scripting code.  "Distribution" is representative for the extra steps you need to take to keep the app store happy.  It is all about packaging, not rebuilding.

Comment: I agree with that from a code-behavior perspective, but as you say, it is about packaging and it's from that perspective that I am looking for differences.  There are actually differences between Debug and Release of the platform-specific native packages produced by building a Cordova project.  For instance, when creating Android packages, Debug configuration uses a cert from the Android SDK to sign the package, but Release requires the developer to create a certificate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Distribution configuration is used when creating app package for iOS App store, it will sign the package with distribution profile. It has no relevance for Android and Windows, Windows Phone platform. Release configuration is used for Android and Windows, Windows Phone platform to create app package for Android or Windows store. Currently visual Studio does not filter the configuration based on platform selected like Android, iOS, Windows etc. and therefore all the configuration is listed even though it might not be applicable to particular platform.